# finding the slide the user is on and comparing it with a slide I what something to happen on

Tags: google-slides

I am trying to detect what slide the user is on and play a different sound for every few slides my [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETvE.png)
have not gotten to sounds yet just trying to get the slide detection working

I tried "===" and "==" and "=" none worked I tried without object id's and that didn't work ether

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I just cant find what slide the user is on and then when they are on say slide 1-4 play a sound track